# Programmatically trigger a shake event on an Android device

Tags: android

How can I implement a shake gesture so it can basically be trigger with a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You write a function that does what your shake is supposed to do.  Then you call that function from both the shake detector and the button's click handler.